# If using specific kernel build Makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm really struggling with this Makefile. I have an application that I want to build on an old Fedora computer but also on a new CentOS computer. I want to change a variable depending on which computer I am using.

This is what I've tried but it doesn't seem to work.

```
UNAME := $(uname -r)
ifeq ($(UNAME),2.6.32.11-99.fc12.x86_64)
        DIRS = Control Simulator
else
        DIRS = Control
endif
```

My question is, how can I get this to work in some standalone Makefile to test? This gives me the "*** No targets. Stop" error currently. After that I should be able to implement it in my real Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you need to provide a target to build.  A makefile that doesn't contain anything other than variable assignments won't do anything.  Maybe you want to add:

```
all:
        @echo 'DIRS = $(DIRS)'
```

to see what value you obtained.

However, I can already see that this won't work as written.  Makefile syntax is not shell syntax, so the statement `$(uname -r)` is trying to expand a make variable named `uname -r` (just like `$(FOO)` is trying to expand a make variable named `FOO`).  That variable is not set, so `UNAME` will always be set to the empty string.

You probably want this instead:

```
UNAME := $(shell uname -r)
```

to invoke the make `shell` function to run a shell script and expand to the results.